# develop website using angular4 and spring mvc

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

For a few days, I am trying to make a simple web project using angular4(client side) and spring(server side) but I can't find any proper solution for it. I am pretty much good in spring and quite familiar with angular. I did a lot research in google about it but can't get any proper solution. Please guys help me out. I would be glad if someone send me some project structure or some sample project. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of solution? SO community is to help in particular problems not to explain or share brief idea about projects. Your questions should not be too broad, ask in particular. Or if you have tried something, show it, or ask exactly what stopping you. Refrain from asking opinionated question or answers. :)

Comment: https://mydevgeek.com/angular-4-crud-application-with-spring-boot-rest-service-part-1/

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community.  - Having said that, I highly recommend you take a look at [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech)

Comment: Follow the GitHub project, which I've posted.I think that's the one you are looking for